# create a simple live drawing board/whiteboard application using flash as3, and flash media server 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server

How do I create a simple live drawing board/whiteboard functionality using flash as3, and flash media server 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with FMS but here is an app I created that does it with Flex, AS3, and BlazeDS:
http://code.google.com/p/jbossflex/